# If $X$ and $Z$ are independent: $\mathbb{E}(Y|X) = \mathbb{E}(Y) \implies \mathbb{E}(Y|X,Z) = \mathbb{E}(Y|Z)$?

Tags: probability, independence

My question is, given that $X$ and $Z$ are independent is it true that

$$
\mathbb{E}(Y|X) = \mathbb{E}(Y) \implies \mathbb{E}(Y|X,Z) = \mathbb{E}(Y|Z) 
$$

I do not seem to be able to prove it but I cannot come up with a counterexample or disprove it.

Does the answer change if on top of $X$ and $Z$ being independent we also impose that $\mathbb{E}(Y|Z) \neq \mathbb{E}(Y)$?

Answer (score 5):

No it is not true

A classic example is where the following triples are equally probable

```
X  Y  Z
0  0  0
0  1  1
1  0  1
1  1  0
```

so $\mathbb{E}(Y|X) = \mathbb{E}(Y) = \mathbb{E}(Y|Z)=\frac12$ but $\mathbb{E}(Y|X,Z) \equiv X+Z \mod 2$ so is $0$ or $1$

Comment: I see, im still interested in whether the statement is true if $\mathbb{E}(Y|Z) \neq \mathbb{E}(Y)$ -edited the question to add this-

Comment: @JRT There would be more counter-examples in that case too